# Failed to send data to Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to push some random data to cloud firestore. So, I have initialized the project using cloud function with - firebase init functions.
Inside the functions dir, I have a file seed.js which has the code to send the data. Using faker to generate the data.

```
const faker = require("faker");

const db = admin.firestore();

const fakeIt = () => {
  return db.collection("customers").add({
    username: faker.internet.userName(),
    avatar: faker.internet.avatar(),
    bio: faker.hacker.phrase()
  });
};

Array(20)
  .fill(0)
  .forEach(fakeIt);
```

When I run node seed.js, I'm getting the error described below

```
PS C:\Users\Ghost\Random Projects\Algolia\functions> node .\seed.js
(node:1636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment.
To learn more about authentication and Google APIs, visit:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
    at _getDefaultProjectIdPromise.Promise (C:\Users\Ghost\Random Projects\Algolia\functions\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:90:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:1636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 21)
(node:1636) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:1636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unable to detect a Project Id in the current environment.
To learn more about authentication and Google APIs, visit:
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
    at _getDefaultProjectIdPromise.Promise (C:\Users\Ghost\Random Projects\Algolia\functions\node_modules\google-auth-library\build\src\auth\googleauth.js:90:31)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're following the example from [fireship.io](https://fireship.io/lessons/algolia-cloud-functions)

If you look at the example you also have to initialise a firebase configuration first

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
```

If this has already been deployed to cloud functions the config will be [automatically provided](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#initialize_without_parameters). If not you will need to provide your firesbase credentials

Comment: Correct. Got it Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize the firebase app at the top of the file

Something like this piece of code

```
admin.initializeApp(Object.assign({}, functions.config().firebase, {
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
}));
```

Comment: No, as per the docs this config is not required when you are using cloud functions

Comment: From Docs- The SDK can also be initialized with no parameters. In this case, the SDK uses Google Application Default Credentials and reads options from the FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable. If the content of the FIREBASE_CONFIG variable begins with a { it will be parsed as a JSON object. Otherwise the SDK assumes that the string is the name of a JSON file containing the options.

Comment: The FIREBASE_CONFIG environment variable is included automatically in Cloud Functions for Firebase functions that were deployed via the Firebase CLI.

Comment: Do you have those variables set then?

Comment: Because from what I see on your example you are trying to make a script that runs outside the "functions" environment. I too have a seeder file to populate the databases and another to reset algolia's indexes and on both I initializeApp() resulting on both working as expected when I `node file.js`

Comment: I have tried with your example, that service account will be the path to the downloaded json file?

Comment: Yes it's the path, I set it like this: `var serviceAccount = require(PATH_TO_FILE)`

Comment: Thanks it worked. But there was a warning --Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail.  Whats that refering to?

Comment: And yes for making it work without the config the project firsts needs to be deployed, as said by @chrimsclarke